# How to get search text from google using Selenium?

Tags: java, dom, selenium, google-search

Below is the code:

```
   driver.navigate().to("https://www.google.com/");
   QBOWebPage.wait(2000);
   WebElement e = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='q']"));
   e.sendKeys("Country");
   e.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
   QBOWebPage.wait(4000);
   String searchText= e.getText();
   Assert.assertEquals(searchText, "Country");
```

Above assertion fails. Search-text comes as empty string.

Comment: And is it actually an empty string in the browser? Or are you using a driver that doesn't show anything on your screen, like HTMLUnit?

Comment: You could run in Debug mode also to step through your code and monitor the Objects.  That would my my suggestion.

Comment: e.getAttribute("value") instead of e.getText() works..

Answer (score 0):

I think the fix is to do something like this instead:

```
driver.navigate().to("https://www.google.com/");
   QBOWebPage.wait(2000);
   WebElement e = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='q']"));
   e.sendKeys("Country");
   e.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
   QBOWebPage.wait(4000);
   WebElement f = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='rso']/li[1]/div/h3") );
   Assert.assertTrue(f.getText().contains("Country") );
```